# Uncaught ReferenceError: msgbox is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
//////////////////main.js file attached
function msgbox (title,text,type,time)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        var img = "<img src='image/"+type+".png' /> ";
        $("#window .wtext").html("<table border='0'><tr><td>"+img+"</td><td>"+text+"</td></tr></table>");
        $("#window .wtitle").html(title);


        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        //$("#window .wtext").css("height",(parseInt($("#window").css("height"),10)-65)+"px");
        get_center("window");
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        $("#window").fadeIn();
        if (time!=0)
        {
            var t = window.setInterval(function(){
                $("#window").fadeOut();
                window.clearInterval(t);
            },time*1000);
        }
    }

//////////////////myajax.js file attached
function toggle_div ()
{
   msgbox("title","text","ok",3);
}
```

I have problem when i call msgbox from myajax.js.
how can i use my function.
it is working from another file.
i should use something for declaring global function?

Comment: Are your functions defined into an anonymous function?

Comment: Make sure your `main.js` script tag is before the `ajax.js` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add both main.js and myajax.js in to your html page within  tag. Then you can call directly to your function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myajax.js"></script>
```